# Bean Validation custom message never works

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation

For this validation (hibernate-validator 6.0.4.Final) into my Spring Boot 1.4.6 app:

```
public class Author {
@Past @NotNull
private LocalDate birth;
@PastOrPresent
private LocalDate death;
...
@AssertTrue(message = "{javax.validation.constraints.author.death}") // custom message code
private boolean isValid() {
    return death == null || death.isAfter(birth);
}
}
```

My custom message never rises. Even if the MessageResource is right:

```
@Autowired
/** see "spring.messages.basename" application property */
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Override // WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource); // custom code ok at DEBUG
    return factory;
}
```

I know many questions and pages exist on this subject. But after hours I still cannot make it to work. Even with a @Bean approach:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource); // DEBUG still ok
    return factory;
}
```

Any good advice, someone? I must be missing something...

> javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.mycompany.demo.domain.Author] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
>   List of constraint violations:[
>       ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='{javax.validation.constraints.author.death}', propertyPath=valid, rootBeanClass=class com.mycompany.demo.domain.Author, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.author.death}'}
>   ]

NB: without "message" parameter specified into the annotation, the default message is converted and localized correctly (interpolatedMessage)

Comment: share the entire Author class

Comment: need more clarity so as to why use {javax.validation.constraints.author.death}" rather than the springs ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Comment: You need to define ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource  bean to Autowire MessageResource class. In ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource you will define you messages properties file and based on your locale correct message will be picked from the property file

Comment: Sorry, I was unsuccessful with adding a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource bean instead of the Spring Boot provided one